# ManyToOne Always Running Queries(always eager)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am using Spring Data JPA (hibernate) with spring boot.

I am having two entities Class

Company   ----- > Employee
With Bi-directional Relation with Each Company have multiple emp.(onetomany from compnay to employee)

**Company Entity**

```
public class Company implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="cmp_id")
    private int cmpId;

    @Column(name="company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="company")
    private Set<Employee> employee;

    ... Getters & Setters   

}
```

**Employee Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column(name="emp_id")
    private int empId;

    @Column(name="emp_name")
    private String empName;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="cmp_id", referencedColumnName="cmp_id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Company company;

    .... Getters & Setters ...
}
```

**Company Service**

```
public class CompanyService {

    @Autowired
    private CompanyRepository companyRepo;

    public Company fetchCompany(int cmpId){
        return companyRepo.findByCmpId(cmpId);
    }
}
```

**Company Repo**

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<Company, Integer>{ 
    public Company findByCmpId(int cmpId);
}
```

API Code(Calling Service Method)

```
@RequestMapping("/cmp/{cmpId}")
    public void findCmp(@PathVariable int cmpId){
        Company cmp = cmpService.fetchCompany(cmpId);
        System.out.println(cmp.getCompanyName());
        Set<Employee> ee = cmp.getEmployee();
        for(Employee e : ee){
            System.out.println(e.getEmpName());
        }
    }
```

Now this api code is firing 5 queries..

```
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_1_, company0_.cmp_id as cmp_id2_1_, company0_.company_name as company_3_1_ from company company0_ where company0_.cmp_id=?
Hibernate: select employee0_.cmp_id as cmp_id4_2_0_, employee0_.id as id1_2_0_, employee0_.id as id1_2_1_, employee0_.cmp_id as cmp_id4_2_1_, employee0_.emp_id as emp_id2_2_1_, employee0_.emp_name as emp_name3_2_1_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.cmp_id=?
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_1_0_, company0_.cmp_id as cmp_id2_1_0_, company0_.company_name as company_3_1_0_ from company company0_ where company0_.cmp_id=?
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_1_0_, company0_.cmp_id as cmp_id2_1_0_, company0_.company_name as company_3_1_0_ from company company0_ where company0_.cmp_id=?
Hibernate: select company0_.id as id1_1_0_, company0_.cmp_id as cmp_id2_1_0_, company0_.company_name as company_3_1_0_ from company company0_ where company0_.cmp_id=?
```

Last 3 queries are result of manytoone join. although i have mentioned it lazy but still it is working as eager. How do I change my code to make it Lazy(basically I need to stop firing these 3 queries).

Answer (score 0):

This seems undesirable, But lazy will load the entities on demand. Please comment out,

```
  Set<Employee> ee = cmp.getEmployee();
  for(Employee e : ee){
       System.out.println(e.getEmpName());
  }
```

And check if the employs are still eager loaded. I think this is the reason for the logs

Comment: It is working fine if I comment out but what if need the employes name?

Comment: @AnkitBansal As the Lazy implies it fetch on demand. if you call cmp.getEmployee(). Then it will bring in the employees, Thats what you need right, unless you get the employees you can not get the names of employees. you can also write another method to fetch employs depending on the company id :).

Comment: What I am asking is that since lazy fetches on demand, Employee  to Company is lazy, so why last 3 queries are firing when I am doing getEmpName() . It should only fire one employee query? Isnt it?

Comment: No when you call cmp.getEmployee(), it will get all the related employees. if you want to get one specific employee. write a specific @query method in  JpaRepository interface

Comment: btw, I asked you to comment out the code, just for you to understand it, look for @Query for more information, otherwise your code does what is asked to do

Comment: Yes that I understand. But why it is fetching company Object inside Employee even though it is lazy fetch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142260/discussion-between-ankit-bansal-and-diyoda).